# Android,Problem:Trying to Send a Link By email

Tags: android

i am sending a simple email and in the body i put a Link .

My problem is the link is not recognize as Link but only as String

Here the code:

```
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{ "Support@bift.net"}); 
       Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverFlow.com/");
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "Check out this great application:"+"\n"+ myUri);  
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Traveler's Pharmacy");
       intent.setType("text/plain");   
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Email Client"));
       startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try settings the type to html instead of plain text. And you will have to use html tags for the link.

Comment: can you please bring an example

Answer (score 10):

Change this two lines:

```
intent.setType("text/html");
```

and

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  
                Html.fromHtml("Check out this great application: <a href=\""+ myUri+
                "\">Link</a>"));
```

Comment: Ahh, forgot to wrap your link in `<a>`. Updated.

Comment: When I send the mail with the help of above code,its not worked for me. I am getting only text.

Comment: This does indeed work, but not in every email app.
It does work in gmail app for example, but not stock email app, on Galaxy S4, API 19.

Comment: @MaxIzrin This does not work. Atleast not on a Nexus 5 with Android 6.0